# Keeping track of online/offline status in real-time with NowJS/Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nowjs-sockets

I've got a site where users login and are connected to NowJS on all pages. I'd like to be able to keep track of their status (online/offline) in near-realtime, but I'm not sure the best way to do this. My initial thought was to just use the connect and disconnect events, but this won't work because those get fired each time the user goes to a new page (since the socket connection is closed while the new page loads).

I've got it somewhat working where I record a timestamp in the database entry for that user on the disconnect event, and then when the connect event fires I check if they've accessed the site within the last 30 seconds. If they haven't, I can assume they are starting a new session. On the disconnect event I use setTimeout to see if they are still online 30 seconds from now, and then set their status to offline if not.

While this mostly works, it seems somewhat hacky and has several edge case issues that could be problematic (not to mention the fact that your going to have a new timeout server-side on each page view). Is there a better way to do this that I'm just overlooking?

Comment: New page = new socket connection. Keep track of the connections for each user, and ignore disconnects if they have another socket open. Sounds right?

Comment: I actually already do that, but there's still the problem that if they only have one page open and are just clicking links, they have no connections open. I currently store all of a user's connections in a group that has their userid as the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was creating a global object that holds the persistent ID for the user (so in this case their ObjectId in MongoDB) as the key and the reference to the setTimeout as the value. I then do clearTimeout on a 'connect' event and delete the key from the object when they are considered offline.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this depends on more than just 'whether there is an open connection'.  Are you trying to display to other users whether someone is around/available for chat/whatever? Then you might also consider an inactivity timeout on the page itself (to capture the times when people walk away from their computer without closing the page). If you're doing something else, like metering usage, you might want a different mechanism.

Comment: Right, but that is more of a feature addition than the core functionality of knowing if they are online or not. Was trying to keep the example as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution here is extending the timeout option for Socket.IO (NowJS uses this internally) or use your hacky solution with setTimeout.

Honestly that seems the best solution considering users can move to another page quickly.

Comment: Are you saying there's a way with socket.io to not trigger a disconnect event on the server until a certain period has occurred?

Comment: Yes, look here https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO at the heartbeat timeout and close timeout params.

Comment: The default for those are 15 and 25 seconds respectively, so unless I'm missing something, that wouldn't do the trick unfortunately.

Comment: So you can either use Socket.IO yourself (NowJS is just an abstraction on top of that) and set the timeouts yourself (modifying the default) OR you can do your 'trick', set a timeout on disconnect. (prolongate the disconnect so to speak)

Comment: No I meant the default in socket.io is 15 & 25 seconds. Those timeouts appear to just pertain to reconnect, they wouldn't have any impact between pages, so the disconnect event will still get fired immediately no matter what those are set to (again, unless I'm looking at it wrong).

Comment: My bad, you're right. You should somehow change Socket.IO to achieve this, look here: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client/blob/master/lib/socket.js#L52 You need to hack that option.